# Access the content of the tags with -xpath -selenium -python

Tags: python, selenium

I try access to content of some tags in a [page](https://www.flashscore.com/match/hzciHz2I/#h2h;overall).

But they are impossible to access.

Here are the first lines of code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.flashscore.com/match/hzciHz2I/#h2h;overall"
driver.get(url)
```

Here is the middle code (the one that pose a problem):

I did two version, here is the first one

```
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
"//table[contains(@class,'h2h_mutual')]/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'highlight')]")))
```

and here is the second one

```
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
"//table[@class='h2h_mutual']/tbody/tr[@class='highlight']")))
```

but it did not find tags and returned an exception 'TimeoutException:'

I not understund why this does not work, someone can help me?

here is the end of the code, that serves to display the content :

```
for elem in data:
     print(elem.text)
```

here is first version in full :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.flashscore.com/match/hzciHz2I/#h2h;overall"
driver.get(url)

data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
"//table[contains(@class,'h2h_mutual')]/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'highlight')]")))

for elem in data:
     print(elem.text)
```

I specify that this page is a window open after click on a link in this [page](https://www.flashscore.com/team/paris-sg/CjhkPw0k/fixtures/) and that I did good the switch between the two page and even perform some actions on it before this one.
(The firsts lines are so there just for that you can reproduce the error quickly)

this is how I proceeded :

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#li2").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#li2")))
window_first = driver.window_handles[0]
link_page = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Nantes']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link_page)
Window_second = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(Window_second)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#a-match-head-2-head").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#a-match-head-2-head")))
```

Comment: What element of the page are you trying to extract?

Comment: the below the page,  from that point 'Head-to-head matches: NANTES - PARIS SG'

Comment: Most of the elements you are finding with your XPATH expression are hidden and only show if you click on 'show more matches' and even then there are more in a hidden div. You could try to wait only for the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comment, most of the elements returned by your XPATH expression are not visible, either because the user needs to click on 'show more results' or because they are in a div with `visibility: none`. If you change your wait to `presence_of_all_elements_located`, it should work.

```
data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,
"//table[contains(@class,'h2h_mutual')]/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'highlight')]")))


print(data[0].text)

>>> '04.02.20 L1 Nantes Paris SG 1 : 2'
```

Some background:
`presence_of_all_elements_located` check if the elements are located, i.e. existing, on the web page but doesn't need them to be visible. `visibility_of_all_elements_located` checks for presence and visibility, i.e. one could say it's a more stringent version of `presence`.

See [Selenium Documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I already click on "show more results" , I just didn't put it here

Comment: @thestar: added some explanation.

Comment: There is a still a hidden div, even after clicking on 'show more results', that's the reason why the wait still times out.